# Date & time - apply current, or 'then' DST?

Tags: time, date-format

I'm designing a function that given a UTC timestamp will convert it to the local time.

The question I have, should the current times DST settings be applied to the conversion, or the timestamps DST settings?

If going with the former, current DST setting applied to timestamp - it would mean 4pm that was recorded with DST+1 would be 3pm with DST+0 and 4pm with DST+0, depending on the time of the year you checked the date at.

If going with the latter, the timestamps DST setting would be applied to it - so 4pm recorded with DST+1 will always say 4pm, no matter what time of the year you've checked it at.

Which is more preferrable in practice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the DST settings applicable to the timestamp.  This will apply the correct conversion rules.  For example if I use the current DST status a local time in January would be incorrectly converted, as I am currently in DST and January uses ST here.

Most languages already have a function or method to do the conversion.  Unless you have strong reasons to write your own, use it.  This code should provide a way to determine if the the timestamp is DST or ST.

Many protocols use a format which includes the offset from UTC, as a suffix.  For example:

```
Delivery-date: Sat, 14 Sep 2013 06:47:18 -0400
```

There are a lot of pitfalls in writing your own code:

- Rules change from time to time.
- Timezone change is often not done at midnight.
- Rules can be different for different locations in the same timezone.
- Leap seconds may or may not be included in the time stamps.

The Olson Time Zone Database contains an accurate rule set and is frequently updated.

Comment: So then-DST settings - thanks!

I'm doing this for Lua, which doesn't quite have it, but has the capabilities to add it.

Comment: @Vadi I see, Lua may not have the space for a full timezone rule set.  You may want to look how the TZ variable is handled by the c library you are using.  It may support applying the current timezone rules for the timezone if specifed in the variable.  This leave you the task of setting it correctly.